# Template format in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tree

I came across the following snippet in the implementation of a N-ary tree in a textbook,

```
template <typename Object, int N>
```

From what I understand, a template's main purpose is to provide "generality" to the code so that a particular variable can be of any type, represented via Object

i.e if you have `template <typename Object>` then we may write the following in the code: `Object variable1;`, where `Object` is of any type.

Based on my description,

1) By specifying a particular variable type (in this case `int` for `N`) arn't we going against the main purpose of templates?

Then...

2)Why would we do this? Isn't it better to include the `N` variable in the constructor?

Comment: this is unclear; what constructor? What int variable?

Comment: Are you sure that you copied the snippet that you are talking about? The rest of the question seems as if you are referring to an example where a non type template argument is used...

Comment: In which case was there `int` for `N`? I don't see where what you've posted shows either.

Comment: @sehe Hi, sorry about that for some reason the int N part got deleted. I hope my edit clears the question up.

Comment: Example for compile-time genericity: A function to compute the L^p metric in a finite-dimensional vector space. No need to make `p` a runtime parameter, this is ideal for compile-time templating. Not every parameter has to be a type, sometimes values make useful parameters, too.

Comment: @Kerrek SB why don't we just initialize p in the constructor? is it only because "compile time templating" is considered ideal? So a value is preferred over a variable?

Comment: @rrazd: Because the templated version doesn't need to pass any variables around. (I'm just talking about a free function, not a class, so no constructors.) There's no need for _runtime_ access to the value of `p`: `const double norm = lpnorm<2>(x);`. The parameter doesn't change at runtime, but I need to have access to several different ones at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, templates can be instantiated on more than just types. They can be instantiated on specific values, if the programmer so desires. In `template<int N> class Foo`, N is treated as a constant, if you will: *instantiate this template and make the constant N have this value*.

Arrays, for example, should be of fixed-size (that's how they are, by definition, expected to behave). Therefore, they should be templated with a given constant size. In the upcoming C++ standard, you can instantiate an array by doing `std::array<int, 7>`; this is an object of type array-of-ints-of-size-seven — yes, the size is a characteristic of the type of an array.

In a nutshell, C++ also allows you to instantiate templates with values, not just with types, because certain types should be defined by a constant value. In the example I gave, the size of the array is a characteristic of the type, not of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is partly wrong.

> By specifying a particular variable type (in this case int for N) arn't we going against the main purpose of templates?

No, because these **non-type template parameters** now allows you to be more specific. Lets take `std::array<T,N>` from C++0x as an example. It is basically a full-blown static-array like `int arr[10];` but with container interface and iterators, aka a way more generic solution.

> Why would we do this? Isn't it better to include the N variable in the constructor?

If you left out the `N`, aka the size, then it would be nothing more than a `std::vector<T>` and you'd have to dynamically allocate the array internally. Non-type template parameters help immensly shifting load from run-time to compile-time, like with the `std::array` if you know the number of elements beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for specifying the value of something using template arguments (rather than a constructor argument) is that it allows the value to be inherited by derived classes.

Also, some constant variables inside a class cannot be initialized using a constructor argument... here's an *ad hoc* example to show you what I mean.

```
template <int n>
struct test
{
    int a:n;
    int b:32-n;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of templates is more general than just allowing types to be substituted. Sometimes there are efficiencies to be gained by knowing an integer value at compile time. The template system was designed to be flexible enough to allow this kind of usage.